# Android SQLite emojis issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an problem understanding how I am supposed to deal with emojis posted from users. I can see that the emoji is arriving to the SQLite database as an image (or font, or what?), but when selected from the database again, I get a question mark of course due to the database not understanding how it should deal with it.

[image]

Any enlightenment will do.

**UPDATE**

Well, utf-8 encoding/decoding was the answer just as the skilfull commenters have pointed.

My encoding:

```
String notes = mNotes.getText().toString();
try {
    // Try to encode due to possible emojis in text
    notes = URLEncoder.encode(mNotes.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
}
arguments.putString(WorkoutDataInputFragment.TEXT_EXTRA, notes);
```

My decoding:

```
try {
    // Try to decode due to possible emojis in text
    mMessage.setText(URLDecoder.decode(workout.message, "utf-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    mMessage.setText(workout.message);
}
```

Comment: get the smiley in UTF-8 format fro server

Comment: The key is dealing with the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Can I change encoding right before I insert to the database?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+encoding+utf+8&oq=sqlite+encoding&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5735j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8